# Unit Test NGRX effect with Marbles for an external URL

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, jasmine-marbles

When an effect is triggered, i would like to test both observables in unit test, to get a 100% code coverage for this part of code. because a `window.location.href` is triggered, I can't test it correctly.

```
export class RouteHelper {
    static redirectToExternalUrl(url: string): any {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Effect

```
@Effect()
handleCreatePaymentSuccess$: Observable<
    {} | routerActions.Go
> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(cartConfigActions.CREATE_PAYMENT_SUCCESS),
    switchMap((action: any) => {
        if (action.payload.redirect) {
            /* istanbul ignore next */
            return Observable.create(
                RouteHelper.redirectToExternalUrl(action.payload.redirect),
            );
        } else {
            return of(
                new routerActions.Go({
                    path: [RouteHelper.paths['validate']],
                }),
            );
        }
    }),
);
```

Test working for the else condition

```
it('should dispatch router action Go on success if no redirect url is provided', () => {
    const payload = { redirect: null };
    const action = new fromCartConfig.CreatePaymentSuccess(payload);
    const completion = new routeractions.Go({
        path: [RouteHelper.paths['validate']],
    });

    actions$.stream = cold('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('-c', { c: completion });

    expect(effects.handleCreatePaymentSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

Test not working for the if condition

```
it('should redirect to url that is returned from api', () => {
    const payload = { redirect: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com' };
    spyOn(RouteHelper, 'redirectToExternalUrl').withArgs(payload.redirect);

    const action = new fromCartConfig.CreatePaymentSuccess(payload);
    const completion = Observable.create(RouteHelper.redirectToExternalUrl);

    actions$.stream = cold('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('-c', { c: completion });

    expect(effects.handleCreatePaymentSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

Can someone explain how to test the If condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
it('should dispatch router action Go on success if redirect url is provided', () => {
    spyOn(RouteHelper, 'redirectToExternalUrl').and.callFake(() => {});
    const payload = { redirect: 'www.buckaroo.nl' };
    const action = new fromCartConfig.CreatePaymentSuccess(payload);

    actions$.stream = cold('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('');

    expect(effects.handleCreatePaymentSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
    expect(RouteHelper.redirectToExternalUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `RouteHelper` injectable and provide a mock implementation during your tests. That way you can verify if the method has been called.